Do all the premade characters' names have some theme or pattern?
It's reported that the 95, 2000 and 2003 starting characters are:

RPG Maker 95: Fess, Lena, Marcus, Agatha, Amy, Khar, Luts and Slobodan
RPG Maker 2000: Alex, Brian, Carol, Deiji/Daisy, Enrike/Enryuu, Arkon/Falcon, Homes/Gomez and Helen
RPG Maker 2003: Zack, Albert, Burns, Klaus/Grace, Arthur, Edith/Ardis, Feylin, Alissa/Alica, Mia, Elene/Eolen, Cynthia, Melissa, Fiona and Mao

Those names are all post-translation, but are there patterns in 95 and 2003 that I'm missing because they've been translated?
2000 has a clear alphabetic pattern, and so does RPG Maker XP, with ABCDEFGH.
Some other versions I know of have their starting characters spell:
RPG Maker VX: RUBY LOVE; RPG Maker VXA: ENTER BRAIN; RPG Maker MV: ???; RPG Maker MZ: ???

This may be better served in GameDevelopment SE. However, as classic software has been known to use popular names as posted by Census Data, it could be using a newer randomization function (think /dev/urandom from linux) and using common dictionaries which are available in most OSes by default now that the internet is much more available.
